# Dynamic variables instead of static causes JS to be slow?

Tags: javascript

I have a library which uses lets say "getAttribute" function of Node a lot. So instead of having it as node.getAttribute(), if I have node[getAttributeStr](), I can have the getAttributeStr as a local string value "getAttribute", which would get minified reducing the size of the code.

My question is, If I do it for all the most frequently used function names, will it slow down the execution as compared to accessing the function directly using the static name?

`node.getAttribute("abc");`

The above code will be replaced by.

```
var getAttributeStr = "getAttribute";
node[getAttributeStr]("abc")
```

My function gets executed quite a lot and hence am afraid if it will increase the execution time a lot.

Comment: You can measure how much slower it is by Yourself. If Your concern is a small code and You are working with the same node, You can minify the function name Yourself: `let g = node.getAttribute.bind(node); g('abc')` or combine both approaches.

Comment: Have a look at this JSPerf (not mine, I found it online): https://jsperf.com/dot-vs-square-bracket/. If you run it several times you'll see that sometimes the dot wins, sometimes the bracket wins. So, based on this very superficial and basic test, I'd say that the differences are not significant.

Comment: It might be better to use a minifier that can just turn `node.getAttribute("abc")` into `a.b("abc")`, which is even shorter than anything using brackets. Also turn on gzip compression on your server to make minification less important.

Comment: @RomanHocke I checked it and couldn't find a big difference for a single time. Thought of finding out if it is a right approach or not, because in none of the popular minifiers, they have an option like this.

Comment: @Thomas As mentioned, I tried with popular minifiers, but they don't do this thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I quickly threw a jsperf-test together, using your example.

https://jsperf.com/dynamic-vs-static-method-call/1

While they're about the same in chrome, the bracket notation seems to be much slower than the static call in firefox. In Edge, the dot notation is about twice as fast on my machine.

[image]

To answer your question, *yes it will slow down the execution to a certain degree in some browsers*.

However, on most modern machines changing one implementation to the other will be barely noticeable. According to the test, you still can call the dynamic getAttribute *300.000 times per second* in the slowest browsers. There are bigger problems with most websites, such as loading 500 KB of tracking scripts and dependencies to display a onepager, requesting non-minified/cached sources, displaying dozens of heavyweight ads etc,  which should be attended to first.

Comment: thanks for your time and reply. Since the application needs to be supported in older browsers as well, I guess it is better for me to go for the static implementation at the cost of file size.

Comment: @jagan you're welcome! Don't forget you can always reduce file size using tools like cssnano https://cssnano.co/